# The difference of speed between queries in transaction blocks

Tags: php, laravel

I have one segment of code that need lock the table to prevent from race conditions.
like:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
$ps = Product::lockForUpdate()->select(['sold', 'seller_id', 'id'])->whereIn('id', $pids)->get();
if($ps->count() > 0) {
....
}
```

I originally thought that the select builder method will make the model not execute the accessor methods, ***but it seems that it didn't work.
I tested the actual delay in Postman, it is far longer than the code***

**The statement above is wrong, the accessor methods were not executed.**
So, my problem becomes why the code below can be so much faster:

below:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
$ps = Product::lockForUpdate()->select(['sold', 'seller_id', 'id'])->whereIn('id', $pids)->where([['sold', '>', 0]])->count();
if($ps > 0) {
....
}
```

The second code is surely faster, but it's almost 10 times faster than the first code. And only in the **DB::transaction** block, the first code will be so slow.
I wonder how the first one is so slow. How many queries the first code will use to generate a model object. Hence, if I always use the ORM code like that, will it seriously hurt the performance? Or maybe it is slow only in the transaction block, if so then why?

Sorry if my words are not clear, English is not my native language.

Comment: nothing is touching an accessor there

Comment: Accessors run when you access a property so you can try to write code that avoids doing that.

Comment: The difference between the two codes is how you're calculating the count. Of course SQL's count is faster than building a collection and then calculating the count on it.

Comment: @IGP I knows that the second code is surely faster. But the delay of the first code is almost 10 times longer than the second code. I wonder how the two code can result in such a large difference. And I found the problems are probably not from accessors after some experiments. So I'll update my questions.

Comment: @Green Sung Which doesn't change my answer. The code below is faster because at the database level, it's just retrieving the count, which then the server returns as a single integer. The code above returns... I don't know how many rows at the database level and then each of those rows are converted into Eloquent Models, which are then placed inside an Eloquent Collection. It's the amount of models you're asking your server to deal with. How big is the count?

Comment: @IGP In my testing situation, only 1~3 rows of data were selected. So I don't understand why it take so long. In the normal situation, the two codes have almost the same testing delay. The delay is so long only in the DB::beginTransaction(); blocks and using lockforupdate(). I mainly wonder how it makes different.

Comment: Can you post the entire transaction code block?